# Can I hide or remove the class name in the shared library?

Tags: c++

I find the class name cannot be hidden in the shared library if this class is polymorphic.  For example,

```
// example.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// #define virtual 

class Base
{
  public:
    virtual const char* whatiam()
    {
        return "Papa";
    }
};

class Child : public Base
{
  public:
    virtual const char* whatiam()
    {
        return "Son";
    }
};

const char* whatiam(Base* obj)
{
    return obj->whatiam();
}

__attribute__((visibility("default"))) const char* TheAPI(int n)
{
    static char buf[64];
    Child t;
    sprintf(buf, "I'm %s.", whatiam(&t));
    return buf;
}
```

I build a share library on Linux with gcc like this

```
$ g++ -fPIC -shared -fvisibility=hidden ../example.cpp -o libexample.so 
$ strip -R .comment -R .note libexample.so
```

Then I open the `libexample.so` as a normal file in Emacs and search, the class name `Base` and `Child` will be find out.

And if I uncomments the statement `// #define virtual` to be `#define virtual`, that is to say make `Base` and `Child` without virtual methods, I find the class name `Base` and `Child` will not be find out in the shared library.

Dose the class name be stored in the class **vtable** by the compiler? Or some other reasons caused this problem?

Comment: I believe this might have something to do with name mangling, although I'm not really sure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I find the class name cannot be hidden in the shared library if this class is polymorphic.

Not clear what kind of hiding you refer to.

From linker symbol visibility perspective all names with internal linkage are hidden. Classes do not have linkage at all, functions and variables do:

```
$ nm -C libexample.so
nm: libexample.so: no symbols

$ nm -D -C libexample.so
0000000000201030 B __bss_start
                 w __cxa_finalize
0000000000201030 D _edata
00000000002010a0 B _end
0000000000000944 T _fini
                 w __gmon_start__
0000000000000728 T _init
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
                 w _Jv_RegisterClasses
                 U sprintf
0000000000000899 T TheAPI(int)
                 U vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info
                 U vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info


$ strings libexample.so | c++filt 
__gmon_start__
_init
_fini
_ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
_ITM_registerTMCloneTable
__cxa_finalize
_Jv_RegisterClasses
TheAPI(int)
sprintf
vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info
vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info
libstdc++.so.6
libm.so.6
libgcc_s.so.1
libc.so.6
_edata
__bss_start
_end
CXXABI_1.3
GLIBC_2.2.5
fffff.
Papa
I'm %s.
5Child
4Base
;*3$"
```

Those strings `5Child` and `4Base` are typeinfo returned by `typeid()`:

```
typeinfo name for Child:
    .string "5Child"
    .hidden typeinfo for Child
    .weak   typeinfo for Child
    .section    .data.rel.ro._ZTI5Child,"awG",@progbits,typeinfo for Child,comdat
    .align 16
    .type   typeinfo for Child, @object
    .size   typeinfo for Child, 24
typeinfo name for Base:
    .string "4Base"
    .hidden typeinfo for Base
    .weak   typeinfo for Base
    .section    .data.rel.ro._ZTI4Base,"awG",@progbits,typeinfo for Base,comdat
    .align 16
    .type   typeinfo for Base, @object
    .size   typeinfo for Base, 16
```

You can disable typeinfo with `-fno-rtti` compiler switch:

```
       -fno-rtti
           Disable generation of information about every class with virtual
           functions for use by the C++ run-time type identification features
           (dynamic_cast and typeid).  If you don't use those parts of the
           language, you can save some space by using this flag.  Note that
           exception handling uses the same information, but G++ generates it
           as needed. The dynamic_cast operator can still be used for casts
           that do not require run-time type information, i.e. casts to "void
           *" or to unambiguous base classes.
```

Comment: @BeyelerStudios `man strings`: _GNU strings prints the printable character sequences that are at least 4 characters long (or the number given with the options below)_.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin Thanks very much. And I wonder how to print out the typeinfo?

Comment: @YantaoXie [`typeid(T).name()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid).

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin I mean how to get those info like `.string "5Child" .hidden ...` posted by you.

Comment: @YantaoXie `g++ -S -fverbose-asm -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden example.cpp -o - | c++filt > example.S`

Comment: @YantaoXie You could actually change those strings in `.S` assembly output and then build an `.o` from that altered `.S` file.